# Upload to vimeo using 'streaming' but do it directly like 'POST'

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a code which lets the user upload a video file to my vimeo pro account. By using POST as the upload method, the user can upload large video files and bypass my web server php file upload limits and restrictions.

However, by using the POST method of the vimeo upload API, I have less control over the upload form because the file upload field is being returned from vimeo and in my situation, I want to use my own file upload field with some text fields to construct the video title.

I tired using 'streaming' before, in order to use my own file upload field, but could not upload files larger then my server limits. Only recently I found out there might be a way to use 'streaming' and still bypass my web server file upload limits, thanks to @Dashron who helped me here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165378/uploading-video-to-vimeo-using-its-api-while-bypassing-php-server-limits

Is that possible? If so, how do I do that or where do I read about it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the PUT upload documentation : https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload#http-put-uploading

And the HTML 5 File documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

This is how Vimeo's on site uploader works. Unfortunately I don't have a ton more information at the moment, but there will be improved documentation in the future!

Comment: But in the meanwhile, I would like to use my own form to upload the file directly. Can that be achieved with streaming (PUT)? I couldn't figure out what did you mean with the references you gave me.

Comment: I've never done it myself, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications looks like a good resource. The idea is you want to load a file using the file input, but read it from JS instead of sending it to a server. As you read it through JS you can stream it directly to vimeo's servers.

Comment: Couldn't figure this out. Decided to use POST upload any only take the upload ticket URL and attach it to my own form.

Comment: I'm trying to upload directly to vimeo from my computer in a wordpress site using `$lib->upload($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],  false);` but it keeps failing. Plus it can't upload large files above 1MB, if you found a way do share please

Comment: https://github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload is an unofficial client side upload library for the Vimeo API